# Very Basic Encryption

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int limit;
char alp[26]={'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','w','x','y','z'};
void encode(char message[21],char enc_message[21],int key);

void decode(char enc_message[21],char dec_message[21],int key);


main()
{



int key,i=0,j=0;
char message[21];
char enc_message[21];
char dec_message[21];
char encrypted[21];
char a='\0';
printf("Input the characters to encrypt\n");
 while(i<21 && a!='\n')
    {
    scanf("%c",&a);
    message[i]=a;
    i=i+1;
    }

for(i=0;;i++) /*custom strlen*/
        {
        if( message[i]= '\0')
            {
            limit=i;
            break;
            }
        }
printf("Input the key");
scanf("%d",key);


for(i=0;i<21;i++)
{
enc_message[i]=message[i];
}


encode(message[21],enc_message[21],key);


for(i=0;i<21;i++)
    {
    dec_message[i]=enc_message[i];
    }

for(i=0;i<limit;i++)
    {
    printf("%c",enc_message[i]);
    }


printf("\n\n");


decode(enc_message[21],dec_message[21],key);


for(i=0;i<limit;i++)
    {
    printf("%c",dec_message[i]);
    }






}







void encode(char message[21],char enc_message[21],int key)
    {
    /*char temp[21];*/
    int x,y;
    for(x=0;x<limit;x++)  /* message check */
        {
        for(y=0;y<26;y++) /* <----- alphabet check */
            {
            if (enc_message[x]==alp[y]) enc_message[x]=alp[y+key];
            }
        }
    }   
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void decode(char enc_message[21],char dec_message[21],int key)
    {
    int x,y;
    for (x=0;x<limit;x++)
        {
        for(y=0;y<26;y++)
            {
            if (dec_message[x]==alp[y+key]) dec_message[x]=alp[y]; 
            }
        }
    }
```

The compiler says,the mistake has to do with the way I call functions(and write them)and says: passing argument1 of 'encode' makes pointer from integer without a cast     ,and that is for argument 2 of 'encode' and the exact same for 'decode'

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't encrypt the code too. Try to write it so that readers don't have to decrypt it.

Comment: Before you bang your head against the wall because your encrypted text is off by one character, add the letter `'v'` to the alphabet! :-)

Comment: You should look into [proper C formatting](http://prohackr112.tk/r/proper-c-formatting). Or learn how to [thoroughly obfuscate your code](//prohackr112.tk/r/proper-c-obfuscation).

Comment: `message[21]` means the 22nd char in `message`

Comment: `if( message[i]= '\0')` --> `if( message[i] == '\0')`, Also  `message` never set `'\0'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing a single element and it's not even a valid element, try

```
decode(enc_message, dec_message, key);
```

Also, format your code so it's readable that is really important, and looping to compute the length of the string to use it in another loop is not a very smart thing, print it in a loop like

```
for (int i = 0 ; enc_message[i] != '\0' ; ++i) ...
```

also, don't over use `break`, just think about the logical condition for the loop, it's the same one where you `break`.  Code is much more readable if the condition appears in the right place.

Comment: The comments helped too but the answer did greatly! It doesn't work succesfully but it is something!